Lease breaking as an International Student
What could be the consequence of breaking a housing lease if I am an international student who has not yet moved to the US?

What do you mean by "breaking a lease"? Just not showing up despite having a lease contract?

You would be liable for the rent until a substitute tenant could be found
And, if that substitute was paying less rent, the difference between what you are liable to pay and what they are liable to pay for the duration of the lease.
Being an international student or not having started the lease is irrelevant.
